# How to solve border overlapping issue in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, quartz-core

I am adding border to the UITableViewCell. Below is the code:

**Try-1:**

```
cell.layer.borderWidth = 1;
cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
```

**Try-2:**

```
cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
```

I have tried both these ways, here is the output.
[image]

As you can find in image, border is overlapping inbetween two cells, because of this color gets darker then the border cells.

Why I have not added table border?

- The problem is, I am using three diff custom cells in single table, according to data, particular cell is loading
- Hence I am not able to add border color to entire uitableview or unable to draw cell borders in cellforrowatindexpath. Because in that method only I am checking which type of data it is, and accordingly custom cell has been loaded.

Here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell*) getTableViewCellForTraining:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withTrainingInfo:(TrainingInfoiOS*)trainingInfo
{
    BeLearnPlatform& ptr = BeLearnPlatform::GetLearnPlatform();

    static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.courseNameLabel.text = trainingInfo.courseName;
    cell.courseStartButton.sectionID = indexPath.section;
    cell.courseStartButton.rowID = indexPath.row;
    cell.tag=0;
 ...
}
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell* cell = nil;
        NSString* dictionaryKey = [self createKeyWithSection:indexPath.section andRow:indexPath.row];
        NSObject* dataObject = [tableViewMappig objectForKey:dictionaryKey];

        if([dataObject isKindOfClass:[MasterCourse class]])
            {
            UITableViewCell* cell = [self getTableViewCellForTraining:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath withTrainingInfo:(MasterCourse*)dataObject];
            return cell;
            }
        else if([dataObject isKindOfClass:[ParentCourse class]])
            {
            UITableViewCell* cell = [self getTableViewCellForParentCourse:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath withTrainingInfo:(ParentCourse*)dataObject];
            return cell;
            }
```

Please suggest me solution for this.

Comment: Add separator in tableViewCell and add border layer to tableView

Comment: I can't do that. There are some cells which have different layout than this. Those are border-less cells. So, I cannot add separator line to entire tableview.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this is the idea.

You can do it like this, add this code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method where you creating cell.

If you want to apply order in the cell at index 1,2 and 3 than...

```
    if (indexPath.row == 1||indexPath.row == 2)
        {

    //Display vertical line on top of the cell
            UIView* vLineview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1)];
            vLineview.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            [cell addSubview:vLineview];
    //Display horizontal line on left of the cell
//44 is default cell size you can change it according to your cell value
    UIView* hLineview1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 44)];
            hLineview1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            [cell addSubview:hLineview1];

    //Display horizontal line on right of the cell
    UIView* hLineview2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(319, 0, 1, 44)];
            hLineview2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            [cell addSubview:hLineview2];
    }
//Now we give last cell to display vertical line on bottom

if (indexPath.row == 3)
            {

        //Display vertical line on top of the cell
                UIView* vLineview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 43, 320, 1)];
                vLineview.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
                [cell addSubview:vLineview];

        //Display horizontal line on left of the cell
    //44 is default cell size you can change it according to your cell value
        UIView* hLineview1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 44)];
                hLineview1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
                [cell addSubview:hLineview1];

        //Display horizontal line on right of the cell
        UIView* hLineview2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(319, 0, 1, 44)];
                hLineview2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
                [cell addSubview:hLineview2];

       //i have added this now
       //Display vertical line on Bottom of the cell
                UIView* vLineview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1)];
                vLineview.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
                [cell addSubview:vLineview];

        }
```

This will add the border in cell which is on 1,2 and 3rd position.
Change view value according to your need. dont set view to bottom otherwise same problem occur.

Comment: Please find update in my question. Sorry for not providing that details earlier. Your solution is perfect if I already know about data. But here at runtime I am checking what type of data coming (Because it is coming through webservice). So I am not able to get what data would be there in next cell.

Comment: Forget about overlapping border. Tell me how you differentiate which tableCiewCell will get border and which is not... bcoz your screenshot display that you are adding some logic to differentiate cell right?

Comment: Through cell identifier. First I check which type of data it is. And accordingly passing diff-diff identifiers.

Comment: Added one method for reference.. Same way there are others with diff cell-identifier and will return cell according to its UI

Comment: Your code supported a lot to achieve a solution. Thanks for that.

Comment: Hi, Problem is still there. We can see darker border when we check in screenshot image and try to zoom out. This difference gets easily caught up in iPad with ratina display and it looks odd.

Comment: Can you display that screenshot? and if your cell is connected than only give top border to cell that is in on top and give all border to cell which is bellow. like , if cell is 1 and 2 that we want to give border, than 1st cell will get `left-right-top` border (Which in code above is 1st and 2nd row) and 2nd cell will get `left-right-top-bottom` border (Which in code above is 3rd row)? you are doing that right?

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation BaseTableViewCell


- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
    UIView *myBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    myBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.backgroundView = myBackView;
    self.backgroundView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    self.backgroundView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor].CGColor;

    self.borderTop = [CALayer layer]; self.borderBottom = [CALayer layer];
    self.borderTop.borderColor = self.tintColor.CGColor; self.borderBottom.borderColor = self.tintColor.CGColor;
    self.borderTop.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 2);
    self.borderTop.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.size.height, self.frame.size.width, 2);
    self.borderTop.borderWidth = 2.0; self.borderBottom.borderWidth = 2.0;
    [self.contentView.layer addSublayer:self.borderTop];
    [self.contentView.layer addSublayer:self.borderBottom];
    self.borderTop.hidden = YES; self.borderBottom.hidden = YES;
    self.clipsToBounds = NO;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
    // set selection color
    UIView *myBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    self.selectedBackgroundView = myBackView;
    self.borderTop.hidden = selected ? NO : YES;
    self.borderBottom.hidden = selected ? NO : YES;
    self.clipsToBounds = selected ? NO : YES;

    myBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    myBackView.layer.borderColor = selected ?  self.tintColor.CGColor : [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor].CGColor;
    myBackView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect r;
    UIView *defaultAccessoryView = self.subviews.lastObject;
    r = defaultAccessoryView.frame;
    r.origin.x = self.bounds.size.width - 50;
    r.origin.y = - self.bounds.size.height/2 + 50;
    defaultAccessoryView.frame = r;

    CGRect frameBack = self.bounds;
    frameBack.size.height += 2;
    self.backgroundView.frame = frameBack;
    self.selectedBackgroundView.frame = frameBack;
}

@end
```